# Sharing Models between Nodejs apps

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i'm trying to share my models between seperate nodejs apps, this is the only way i can think of to keep the same models in sync between 3-5 apps

here is my project structure

```
- app1
- app2
- app3
- shared
--models
---user.js
```

here is the package.json dependencies in all shared project

```
"mongoose": "^5.5.2",
"mongoose-sequence": "^5.0.1"
```

here is the package.json dependencies for all other projects

```
    "shared": "file:../shared",
```

and here is how i tried using the shared models

```
let User = require('shared/models/user')
```

I get no errors while running the project but all my requests are just pending (browser keeps loading) basically it goes into an endless wait period....nothing happens...

i have no idea where i messed up